# ng-Grid with ng-repeat horizontal headers

Tags: javascript, css, html, angularjs, ng-grid

Hey thanks for checking out my question, I am trying to create headers in ng-grid with an ng repeat but horizontally. I am able to the ng-repeat working but the items are repeating vertically. Is it possible to make them horizontal?

Here is my template:

```
headerCellTemplate: '<div ng-repeat="day in dayInfo" ng-class="col.colIndex()" >{{day.dayId}}</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

These elements are repeating vertically because you are using `div`'s, which are block-level elements. To solve this, you can change your template to use an inline element like `span`:

```
<span ng-repeat="day in dayInfo" ng-class="col.colIndex()" >{{day.dayId}}</span>
```

You could use either add a CSS rule that styles these div's as `inline` or `inline-block`, but using `span`'s is probably easiest.